# How do I find $\text{sup}\{|f_n(x)|\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Given $f_n : [0, \infty) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of functions, defined by $$f_{n}(x) = \frac{x}{n^2}\ e^{\frac{-x}{n}} $$

for $n \geq 1$

I am trying to prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly to the zero function by showing that $$\delta_{n} := \text{sup}\{|f_n(x)| : x \in [0, \infty) \}
 \longrightarrow  0$$
but I don't understand $\delta_{n}$ very well. Does it depend on $n$? How do I actually find it?

Comment: You don't need to find $\delta_n$ explicitly. It would suffice to find constants $C_n$ such that $C_n$ tends to zero and $\delta_n \leq C_n$ for each $n$

Comment: So I am trying to find a sequence $a_{n}$ that tends to zero, such that $|f_n(x)| < a_{n}$ for all $x$ ?

Comment: Yes, that would do it for you, right?

Comment: You can show using calculus that $f_n(x)$ has a global maximum at $x=n$, thus $\sup\limits_{x\in [0,\infty)} |f_n(x)|=\sup\limits_{x\in [0,\infty)} f_n(x)=\frac{1}{e\cdot n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that the supremum tends to $0$, not to necessarily find the supremum *exactly*. Namely, it is sufficient to find $(a_n)_n$ such that
$$
\forall n\geq 1,\qquad \sup_{x\in[0,\infty)} \lvert f_n(x)\rvert \leq a_n 
$$
and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n =0$.

Therefore, let's try and do that here: for all $x\geq 0$ and $n\geq 1$,
$$
0 \leq \frac{x}{n^2} e^{-\frac{x}{n}} = \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{x}{n} e^{-\frac{x}{n}}  \leq \frac{1}{n}\cdot \sup_{t\in[0,\infty) } t e^{-t} \stackrel{\rm def}{=} a_n
$$
*(can you see why?)* But it is easy to study the function $h(t) = t e^{-t}$: it is differentiable, and $h'(t) = e^{-t}(1-t)$, and it is near-immediate to conclude it achieves its maximum at $t=1$, where $h(1) = 1/e$. Therefore, in light of the above you have
$$
\forall n\geq 1,\qquad \sup_{x\in[0,\infty)} \lvert f_n(x)\rvert \leq \frac{1}{en} 
$$ 
and you can conclude.

---

Note: in this case, it so happens that the $a_n$ we found is actually **equal** to $\sup_{x\in[0,\infty)} \lvert f_n(x)\rvert$.

Comment: Thank you! that's really helpful :)

Comment: @maa'our You're welcome -- glad this helped!